# sb40c storage blade troubleshooting

Tags: storage, hp, blade-chassis

we have in our bladesystem c3000 (hp 469499-b21) a bl460c blade partnered with a sb40c storage blade as DAS. the bl460 is running diskless and the storage blade has 4 drives configured as raid 10 array.

on the storage blade is a blinking red light. the enclosure health summary on the insight display keeps alternating between "healthy", and "warning" stating a device error in the storage server's bay.

in the iLO log it also keeps alternating between a "temperature sensor failure in bay.." and an "OK" as in -all systems go- status. im very concerned about this esepcially since this morning the blade server failed to start because of the faulty storage server showing a device error and sometimes degraded status and wouldnt work until i pulled out with its blade server and plugged them back in. i found no record online about this error stated in iLO logs.

is my data compromised? i plan to get a spare ASAP but im worried disaster will strike soon.

could this be an iLO firmware issue that would get resolved by upgrading?

in case i managed to provide a new storage blade, is it sufficient to just attach the hard drives into the new one without any configuration or so? or is there something that needs to be done?

please note that we have another blade+storage blade that are working properly and not showing any warnings or errors whatsoever. i realize this is most likely a hardware failure in the storage blade itself, because when switched the 2 pairs of devices from bays 1-2 to 5-6 and vice versa, the error remained with the original device so its not a bay location or enclosure thing. my fans and power supplies are of course set in the correct way to accomodate 4 blades.

im sorry if im lacking vital details to provide u with, anything u can share will be helpful!

Comment: Almost certain it's not an iLO issue but you need to contact HP to resolve this, I'm pretty sure you've got a very real hardware problem and only they will be able to fix it.

Comment: how about the OA? could it be related somehow?

Comment: Definitely something wrong. Don't waste your time, call HP and get some use out of the warranty.

Comment: @user57182 - no, nothing OA related.

Answer (score 2):

for people having this same problem (i doubt anyone will experience it) with the exact OA error logs that were repeating with a few seconds between them were:

*Blade x Ambient Temeperature Sensor fault...state is DEGRADED.*

*Blade x is reporting normal health status.*

*Blade in bay #x status changed from Degraded to OK.*

*Blade x  Ambient Temperature state is OK.*

the hp support at our only local hp partner was of no help at all. thankfully after many hours of banging my head against the wall and disecting every inch of storage blade's components, turns out the jack that's apparently that of the temperature sensor was on backwards. boy was that a relief! check the picture to see what i mean. thanks everyone!

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised it's not a keyed connector (like SATA power, with a tab preventing back-to-front insertion)

Comment: that would've been much more practical Tom

Comment: Nice. Slightly annoying, but nice.

Comment: It just happened to me now. Out of nowhere we received the warnings in 1 sec delay `Blade 2 Ambient Temperature Sensor fault...state is DEGRADED.` and immediately after that 
`Blade 2 Ambient Temperature Sensor state is OK.` We have c3000 blade enclosure and on blade 2 there is a tape blade. I'm gonna ignore this for awhile but if it happens again I will see if there is a jack for a temperature sensor inside. Thanks for documenting this thou :)

Answer (score 1):

Your data is safe if you move the disks (together, keep them in order) to another SB40 unit. I suspect that this is an issue with the storage blade unit (temperature sensor failure). Call HP Support or open a case on the online [Support Case Manager](http://www13.itrc.hp.com/service/mcmBsc/homepageRequest.do?hpappid=hppcf&urlAfterDropPage=http://www13.itrc.hp.com/service/mcmBsc/homepageRequest.do?lang=en-us&admit=109447627%201250445955947%2028353475&cc=us).